# Fetching data from the Database, not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm wondering if someone can help me, because I'm stuck:) the script does not work correcly:/

the records in "Naam" are fetched, looped and the table is displayed:
[image]
But the data from "product" doesn't show. So my point is: Can someone help me get the products data from the DB, thanks in advance

```
                <?php

            require_once('Includes/connect.php')

            ?>

            <?php

            if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="add"){

            $id=intval($_GET['id']);

            if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])){

            $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++;

            }else{

            $sql_s="SELECT * FROM product
            WHERE id_product={$id}";
            $query_s=mysql_query($sql_s);
            if(mysql_num_rows($query_s)!=0){
            $row_s=mysql_fetch_array($query_s);

            $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]=array(
            "quantity" => 1,
            "price" => $row['price']
            );

            }
            else
            {
            $message="Het product ID is ongeldig!";
            }
            }
            }

            echo "<h1>Producten lijst Kerstbomen</h1>";

            if(isset($message))
            {
            echo "<h2>$message</h2>";
            }
            else
            {

            $table_thead = '
            <table>
            <tr>
            <th><ID/th>
            <th>Id produkt</th>
            <th>size</th>
            <th>diameter</th>
            <th>tips</th>
            <th>nr_of_bulb</th>
            <th>cu_ft</th>
            <th>l</th>
            <th>w</th>
            <th>h</th>
            <th>cbm</th>
            <th>g_w</th>
            <th>n_w</th>
            <th>stand</th>
            <th>pack</th>
            <th>warehouse</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>barcode</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>
            ';


            $sql_getName = "
            SELECT *
            FROM naam
            ORDER BY name ASC
            ";

            $query_getName = mysql_query($sql_getName);


            while( $row_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_getName) )
            {

            $curName = $row_name['name'];


            $sql_getProduct = "
            SELECT *
            FROM product
            WHERE id_name = '$name';
            ";

            $query_getProduct = mysql_query($sql_getProduct);


            echo ($row['id_name']);



            print $table_thead;


            while( $row_Product = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_getProduct) )
            {
             echo "
            <tr>
            <td> ".$row['id_product']."</td>
            <td>".$row['size']."</td>
            <td>".$row['diameter']."</td>
            <td>".$row['tips']."</td>
            <td>".$row['nr_of_bulb']."</td>
            <td>".$row['cu_ft']."</td>
            <td>".$row['l']."</td>
            <td>".$row['w']."</td>
            <td>".$row['h']."</td>
            <td>".$row['cbm']."</td>
            <td>".$row['g_w']."</td>
            <td>".$row['n_w']."</td>
            <td>".$row['stand']."</td>
            <td>".$row['pack']."</td>
            <td>".$row['warehouse']."</td>
            <td>".$row['price']."</td>
            <td>".$row['barcode']."</td>
            <td>".$row['id_name']."</td>
            <td> <b></b> <input class='quantity' type= 'text' name='aantal' size='2' maxlength='2' value='1'/></td>
            <td><a href='index.php?page=product&action=add&id=".$row['id_product']."'>Product toevoegen</a></td>
            </tr>";

            }


            echo "</table>";
            }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: $row['id_product'] should be $row_Product['id_product'] right?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).